# How to transform string with objects and array indexes into json

Tags: java, arrays, json, freemarker

I receive from another program Map with string representation of elements:

```
Map<String,String> properties = new HashMap<String,String>() {{
    put("news[0].title", "Title 1");
    put("news[0].body",  "Body 1");
    put("news[1].title", "Title 2");
    put("news[1].body",  "Body 2");
}};
```

I need to render it into freemarker-template. In question

[freemarker-flat-structure-of-passing-parameters-transfer-to-array-of-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723088/freemarker-flat-structure-of-passing-parameters-transfer-to-array-of-objects)

we decided that it is impossible to parse this kind of values in freemarker. But freemarker can eval json.

So I need to know how to transform this map into objects or json. I need something like that:

```
{
    "news": [
        {"title": "Title1", "body": "Body1"},
        {"title": "Title2", "body": "Body2"}            
    ]
}
```

Names of parameters in map are unknown, not exactly "news", not exactly "title" and "body", I don't know.
May be there are some libraries for such purposes?

Comment: Have you tired Json Simple?

Comment: Check out this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155800/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-json-object-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using your own language there, just write a parser for it. It's not a complex language after all. Also, transforming it to JSON doesn't make sense, based on what I know about the problem. Yes, the FTL expression syntax and JSON syntax overlaps quite much. But you shouldn't parse anything inside the FTL-s, just parse your language to `List`-s and JavaBeans and/or `Map`-s, and pass that plain Java object to FreeMarker.

Answer (score 0):

[GSon](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) libraries are there for conversion between Java objects and JSON strings.